# Verifying electronic signature from passport using bouncycastle in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

Trying to verify a signature for the data in a passport using BouncyCastle for .NET. The same passport signature has been verified by other applications as correct.

The following code is the current progress, which returns a false as the result.

```
var asn1setdata = Asn1Set.FromByteArray(eContent); //Results in properly parsed dataset
var derEncodedASN1Set = asn1setdata.GetDerEncoded();

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert1 = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(documentSignerCertficateBytes); //Correct certificate attributes after parsing
RsaKeyParameters ecPublic = (RsaKeyParameters)cert1.GetPublicKey();

//create a signerutility with type SHA-256withRSA 
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");

signer.Init(false, ecPublic);
signer.BlockUpdate(derEncodedASN1Set, 0, derEncodedASN1Set.Length);

var verified = signer.VerifySignature(documentSignatureBytes); //returns false
```

The asn1set is parsed and gives proper data in the object.

The x509 cert is parsed properly and shows SHA-256withRSA.

The signer is created with the correct algorithm.

Is the method I am using correct?

Comment: The signing algorithm used to sign the certificate need not be the same as the signing algorithm used to sign the data. That algorithm is possibly available in some metadata associated with the signature, or in the specification, or both.

Comment: That `RsaKeyParameters ecPublic` certainly looks suspicious... Are you sure it's an RSA pub key and not an EC pub key?

Comment: @JamesKPolk was right, I was using the wrong algorithm.

Comment: Hey, how did you manage to verify posted data from the card? I can verify in my Java app that eContent fits the signature, but how do you know what is the source string of the eContent/signed data so that I can do the verification of data I actually post (first name, last name, date of birth...)?